# How would I validate unique selects, within nth sub sets of selects?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that is generated dynamically.

```
<p>
   Class Choices 1 </br>
   <select name="1_option_1">
      <option value=4>2x3 Study Time</option>
      <option value=5>2x3 Science Time</option>
      <option value=6>2x3 Math Time</option>
   </select>
   choice 1 </br>
   <select name="2_option_1">
      <option value=4>2x3 Study Time</option>
      <option value=5>2x3 Science Time</option>
      <option value=6>2x3 Math Time</option>
   </select>
   choice 2 </br>
   <select name="3_option_1">
      <option value=4>2x3 Study Time</option>
      <option value=5>2x3 Science Time</option>
      <option value=6>2x3 Math Time</option>
   </select>
   choice 3 </br>
</p>
<p>
   Class Choices 2 </br>
   <select name="1_option_2">
      <option value=1>2x3 Knitting</option>
      <option value=2>2x3 Computers</option>
      <option value=3>2x3 Having Fun</option>
   </select>
   choice 1 </br>
   <select name="2_option_2">
      <option value=1>2x3 Knitting</option>
      <option value=2>2x3 Computers</option>
      <option value=3>2x3 Having Fun</option>
   </select>
   choice 2 </br>
   <select name="3_option_2">
      <option value=1>2x3 Knitting</option>
      <option value=2>2x3 Computers</option>
      <option value=3>2x3 Having Fun</option>
   </select>
   choice 3 </br>
</p>
```

The above code follows these rules.

For all (nth) Class Choices (block?)

- If a Class Choice (block?) has 2 classes, then two choice option selects are generated.
- If a Class Choice (block?) has 3 classes, then three choice option selects are generated.
- ...
- If a Class Choice (block?) has n classes, then Nth choice option selects are generated.

Note I generated unique select names with the intention that this could make finding unique sets easier. If that is not the case I can change the given to have more uniformed names. Also, I can add class names or other properties as needed. I am new to html and scripting so I am doing lots of guess work.

No requirements for scripting languages.

How would I validate unique selects, within nth sub sets of selects?
That is, for each Choice block, enforce unique values for options.

For example:

Rejected inputs

```
Class Choices 1 != 4,4,4  
Class Choices 1 != 4,4,5  
Class Choices 1 != 4,4,6 
...
Class Choices 1 != 5,5,5  
Class Choices 1 != 5,4,4  
Class Choices 1 != 5,6,6  
...
Class Choices 1 != 6,6,6  
Class Choices 1 != 6,6,5  
Class Choices 1 != 6,4,4  
...
```

For any duplicates

Accepted inputs

```
Class Choices 1 == 4,5,6  
Class Choices 1 == 5,6,4  
Class Choices 1 == 6,5,4  
...
```

The scope of the validation should relate to Class Choice(s).
That is Class Choice 1, Class Choice 2, ... Class Choice N

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: In the title. How would I validate unique selects, within nth sub sets of selects?

Comment: @user136952 I'm a bit confused as well...

Comment: added an example.

Comment: So in case of 10 choices people have to come up with 10 different priority list choices?

Comment: @RST correct, that is the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the gist for solving this task.

```
$(function(){
  $('select').change(function(){
    var enabled = [];
    
    $('.group').each(function(){
      var values = [];
      $(this).children('select').each(function(){
        var value = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        // fills the enabled array with true or false depending if the value is unique to the group; 
        enabled.push(areWeSpecialYet(values, value));
        
        values.push(value);
      });
    });
    // enables the button if all are unique.
    enableTheButton(enabled);
  });
});
```

If you're interested you can check the working example here, it will work with any number of groups or options:

### [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ciseci/edit?js,output)

Comment: Does the `#` in '$('#option_N')' act as wild card?'  Also the issue I am seeing with this solution. Is the amount of options are unknown until runtime. So there could be 2, 3 ... N options.

Comment: Ah sorry for not mentioning this is using the jQuery library. It just makes writing js better and faster. The **#** stands for **ID**

Comment: @user136952 is my answer not what you were looking for?

Comment: right. It is not working correctly. [link](http://jsbin.com/tilebofinu/edit?html,js,output)  Additionally, your code assumes there are only 3 options, where I am asking about Nth amount of options.

Comment: In the example I've provided? What's off?

Comment: Here is the [link](http://jsbin.com/tilebofinu/edit?html,js,output)  your code assumes there are only 3 options, where I am asking about Nth amount of options, or Nth amount of Class choices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127835/discussion-between-mihailo-and-user136952).

Comment: @user136952 If you're still struggling I've updated my answer, to fix your problem completely.